# is this function is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

is this function is measurable? $f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2 + x^3& \text{if}~ x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
\sin(x)&\text{if}~x\notin \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$

Comment: Measurability of a function is not determined by editting it on a measure zero subset, so you are just asking measurability of sine, which follows from continuity.

Comment: It's important to specify which type of measurability you are asking about.  Do you mean Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: yes ...i mean lebesgue measurable

Comment: @waladraidi Do you know anything about the Borel sigma algebra?

Comment: yes..i kown about borel meaurability

Comment: @waladraidi Ok, well hopefully you know that the Borel sigma algebra is a subset of the sigma algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets.  So any function that is Borel measurable is Lebesgue measurable.  Now, continuous functions are Borel measurable, so they are Lebesgue measurable.  That shows that $x^{2} + x^{3}$ and $\sin{x}$ are Lebesgue measurable, since they are continuous which implies they are Borel measurable, which implies they are Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @waladraidi Finally, since $\Bbb Q$ is a countable set, it is Lebesgue measurable (all countable sets are), so $\chi_{\Bbb Q}$, the characteristic function of $\Bbb Q$, is Lebesgue measurable.  (Also, since $\Bbb Q$ is Lebesgue measurable, so is $\Bbb Q^{c}$.)  Finally, we can express the function $f$ as $(x^{2} + x^{3})\chi_{\Bbb Q}(x) + (\sin{x})\chi_{\Bbb Q^{c}}(x)$.  Each of these terms is a product of Lebesgue measurable functions, so each term is Lebesgue measurable, so the sum is Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(x)=(x^2+x^3)\chi_{\Bbb{Q}}(x)+sin(x)(1-\chi_{\Bbb{Q}}(x))$